# Using C++ to add a JPG file to an outputted HTML file

Tags: html, c++

I'm writing a program in C++ that creates an HTML file (to be opened in Word and sent as a physical letter), and I would like to add two JPG images (the letterhead and a signature file), but I'm still pretty new to this and not having much luck finding an answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string date = "Today";

letter.open("letter.html", ios::out);
letter << "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>"
       << "<style></style></head><body>"
       << // I want letterhead.jpg on this line!
       << "<div>" << date << "</div>" // etc.
```

Any tips on how I might accomplish this? I've only dealt with data/text files so far; I'm not sure how to access image files and use them in output.

Comment: `<img src="letterhead.jpg">`?

Comment: Wow, it was really that easy. I thought for sure I needed to open the image file in the C++ program. This is fantastic! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: HTML deals with images just with the path, you don't need any reading operation :) you could edit your letter.html with a simple text editor, no need of C++ for that... are you sure you need C++? ahah

Comment: I probably don't *need* C++, but I've only been programming for a year and this is the language I know best. The program performs a number of functions before generating one of four letters at the end. I've been manually copying the letter text from .txt files to Word files, so creating that Word doc automatically is the next step in making this program better. Thanks so much for helping me get it there! :)

Comment: Oh I see :) go on then, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
<< "<img src='letterhead.jpg'>"
```